# Is there an auto-upgrade library / framework available for windows that has similar features as the ones Sparkle for Mac OSX provides?

Tags: c++, windows, deployment, setup-deployment

Our app is built using Qt and I would like to use a framework similar to Sparkle in our Windows version, to replace our custom solution. Is there anything like this ?

Answer (score 2):

Google has their update framework open-sourced: https://github.com/google/omaha. But the server side is not there, there is a paper about the protocols in the wiki though.

Answer (score 2):

There's now a Windows port of Sparkle, see http://winsparkle.org.

Answer (score 1):

Windows has BITS APIs for writing auto-update components. Check it out here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362827(VS.85).aspx 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188766.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is a long list of auto-update frameworks:

http://www.fredshack.com/docs/auto_update.html